# SQL evaluation arguments from a file in sqoop eval

Tags: hadoop, eval, sqoop

Are there any option to run a SQL evaluation argument from a file rather than hard-coding the sql statement with --query parameter during sqoop eval?

For example:

```
sqoop eval -D mapreduce.job.queuename=NONP.XXXX --connect "jdbc:oracle:thin:ABC/PSCODE@XXX.XX.XX.com:61901/XXX_ANY" --username XXXX --password DXX --query "TRUNCATE TABLE SAMPLE_STG_TABLE DROP STORAGE" ;
```

I want to store the statement `"TRUNCATE TABLE SAMPLE_STG_TABLE DROP STORAGE"` in a file statement.sql and run sqoop eval using  statement.sql
What parameter should I use in place of --query (-e?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
sql=`cat statement.sql`
sqoop eval -D mapreduce.job.queuename=NONP.XXXX --connect "jdbc:oracle:thin:ABC/PSCODE@XXX.XX.XX.com:61901/XXX_ANY" --username XXXX --password DXX --query "$sql";
```

Comment: @MayukhMukhopadhyay, I'm happy to help! If my answer is useful, vote up, please!

Comment: I'm severely under-aged as per stack overflow to be eligible to vote (need +15 points to vote, I have reached 8) :)